# java command accessing text files

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I want to run my project in the command line with the java command but I get an error,

> input.txt (no such file or directory)

In my program I am reading from the file input.txt and when I compile and run the program from eclipse it works completely fine without any problems, but with the java command I keep on receiving that error.

My project is structured as so

Project

- src
- bin
- input.txt

The command I am running is(exact path and classname not given)

> java -cp Path/to/Project/bin classname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the command from project directory then it will work fine. But If you run command from any other directory then it will search in that directory for file `input.txt` so error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning that it is always recommended to write the full file path
e.g.: `"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\src\\bin\\input.txt"`

The double `\\` are important, otherwise the compiler won't recognize the `\`.
Dont forget the `"` when giving the filepath.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use cmd, don't use powershell.
2. Use `cd [the directory with your Test.java and input.txt file]` to go to that directory.
3. Use `java Test.java < input.txt` to read from the text file. You don't need to use javac to compile first if your java version is high enough.
4. Try `java [packageName].Test.java < input.txt` if you use a package in eclipse.

code example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You have entered: " + s);
    }
}
```

input.txt

```
Java file input using command line.
```